# What is the molecule responsible of the yellow color of the Agave americana?

Tags: molecular-biology, botany, plant-physiology, plant-anatomy

Does anybody know what is the molecule responsible of the yellow color at the edges of this plant? 
I noticed also that the new forming yellow part at the begging stage is soft green until it is exposed to light. After the exposition to sun light it change from soft green to yellow(like that of the image bellow). 
Does anybody have any explanation?

[image]

Comment: Xanthophylls, I would guess. These are leaves and all leaves do contain Xanthophylls but the green colour due to chlorophyll dominates. These parts of leaves do not produce chlorophyll.

Comment: I think that your explanation is good. But I do not know why this type of  evolutionary adaptation...If there is no chlorophyll but only  
Xanthophylls all the yellow parts are useless in therm of photosynthesis, I guess.

Comment: Yes. These parts are non-photosynthetic.